# Как написать слово "firewall", используя правила русского языка.

Tags: иностранные-слова

Приветствую всех участников форума! Я не могу понять как правильно писать слово "firewall" по-русски. Видел два варианта: файрволл и фаерволл, но я думаю, что надо писать так: файерволл (как фейерверк). Так какой же из вариантов правильный? Или правильных вариантов здесь нет?

Comment: Лучше используйте термин брандмауэр. Его правописание уже зафиксировано.

Comment: Ну, как вариант, синоним "брандмауэр" использовать можно. Мне просто хотелось узнать как правильно по-русски писать "firewall", так как я видел несколько различных вариантов.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Слово пока не имеет словарной фиксации, таким образом можно говорить лишь о более или менее предпочтительных вариантах. 
На мой взгляд наиболее точно соответствует принятым соглашениям на передачу подобных слов вариант "фаервол". Во-первых,непроизносимое удвоение согласных на концах слов обычно не сохраняются (балл, кристалл и металл - исключения, имеющие свою причину), а во-вторых, за единичными исключениями Й перед Ю, Я, Е и Ё не пишется из-за избыточности. Фейерверк и несколько других слов - исключения, которые, кстати, неоднократно предлагалось убрать, последний раз - Орфографической комиссией под руководством проф. В. В. Лопатина.

Answer (score 2):

Чем так мучиться, гораздо умнее и достойнее было бы не обезьянничать перед американцами, а придумать своё русское слово, как это делают французы, арабы, китайцы и все, уважающие себя народы.

Comment: >придумать своё русское слово

Например?
Огневал?

Answer (score 1):

Если по-русски дословно - стена огня---но уже есть  пожар. Брандмайор, устаревшее с немецкого это защитник от пожара, типа главный по "тарелочкам", по огню, а у нас Пожарный.
А англоязычное как-то не катит в силу смыслового несоответствия слов и действия...
Самое простое это не выдумывать новых слов и канцеляризмов, типа межсетевой экран или программнотехнический комплекс защиты от несанкционироаванного доступа, а просто применить слово защита. И правы те, кто ратует за отказ от иностранщины, уж больно она  по национальному самолюбию цепляет, брендит и мерчендайлит, файерит, но и  неволит, чисто по-русски.
Как-то все не по-нашему, надоедает своей настырностью.

Answer (score 0):

Вполне естественно, что этому слову до закрепления в нашем языке еще очень далеко. В обыденном трёпе сетевиков более употребим жаргонизм "фаер". Ну а более-менее устоявшимся канцеляризмом является "межсетевой экран". Я, например, обычно пишу "файрвол".